# Работа со списками, словари

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари, индексы

Здравствуйте передо мной стоит такая задача:

> Создать список (библиотека книг), состоящий из словарей (книги).
>
> - Словари должны содержать как минимум 5 полей  (например, номер,
>     название, год издания...). В список добавить хотя бы 10 словарей.
>
> Создать список (библиотека книг), состоящий из словарей (книги).
>
> - Словари должны содержать как минимум 5 полей  (например, номер,
>     название, год издания...). В список добавить хотя бы 10 словарей. 
>     Конструкция вида:  `library = [{"id" : 123456, "title" : "Война и мир"`,
>     `"author" : "Толстой",...} , {...}, {...}, ...]`.
>
> Реализовать функции:
>
> - вывода информации о всех книгах;  – вывода информации о книге по
>     введенному с клавиатуры номеру;  – вывода количества книг, старше
>     введённого года;
> - обновлении всей информации о книге по введенному
>     номеру;  – удалении книги по номеру.  Провести тестирование функций.

Вот так я попытался решить эту задачу :

```
library = [{"id": 12,\
            "title" : "В интересах революции",\
            "group" : "Агата Кристи"},\
            {"id": 13,\
            "title": "Серебро",\
            "group":"Би-2"},\
            {"id":14,\
            "title": "Люди на холме",\
            "group":"Наутилус Помпилиус"},\
            {"id": 15,\
            "title" : "Uselink",\
            "group": "Depeche Mode"}]

def listAll(x,lib):
    for i in range(len(library)):
        el = '{},{},{}'\
             .format( lib[i].get('id'),\
                      lib[i].get('title'),\
                      lib[i].get('group') )
        return el

def outByNums(x,lib):
    for i in range(len(library)):
        el_sym = lib[i].get('id')
        if int(x) is el_sym: 
            el2 = '{},{},{}'\
                  .format( library[i].get('id'),\
                  lib[i].get('title'),\
                  lib[i].get('group') )
    return el2

def popByNums(x,lib):
    for i in range(len(library)):
        el_sym1 = lib[i].get('id')
        if int(x) is el_sym1: 
            lib.pop(i)
    return lib

x_in = int(input())
print(popByNums(x_in,library))
```

Мой вопрос такой: если в функции ***popByNum( )*** поиск i-го элемента проходит нормально и я даже могу вернуть его индекс, то когда я пользую свойство .pop(i) то происходит ошибка:

```
 File "task562.py", line 46, in popByNums
    el_sym1 = lib[i].get('id') IndexError: list index out of range
```

я не понимаю, почему такое происходит, и как вообще можно удалить элемент по этому индексу, неужели придется переводить список в еще один словарь и работать с ним ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы удаляете книгу, список сокращается, а индекс и дальше идёт до старой длины списка.
Я бы изменил функцию следующим образом:

```py
def popByNums(id, lib):
    for i, book in enumerate(lib):
        if id == book['id']: 
            lib.pop(i)
            return lib
```

Т.е. сразу после нахождения нужной книги мы выходим из функции, и цикл не продолжает свою деятельность

Comment: Ясно, спасибо, действительно очевидное решение, как-то сразу не дошло.